# Symbol clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Okay, so I've read a few different meanings for the exclamation point in a statement. For example: $$!\exists x \in O \ni 2x < 5$$

The only question I have is about the Exclamation point in front of the "there exists" symbol. I know it's also used in permutations, but that's a slightly different concept (I think)

Any clarification would be fantastic, thank you

Comment: I know that "Exclamation" after "there exists" symbol stands for uniqueness, i.e., $\exists !$ will be read as "there exists unique". May be this might also mean the same or there can by some typing error....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the exclamation point is "used in permutations", as you put it, it signifies a [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

When the exclamation point is used with a "there exists" symbol $\exists$, it means "there exists **a unique**..." ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification)) However, it should go in the order $\exists!$, not $!\exists$ like you've written.

Comment: Okay, thank you! the example was one given by my instructor, so he might have made a typo. Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! It may take a few minutes to become visible, but there's a green checkmark you can click if this answer is satisfactory.